# How can I get the data from the `*.bin` file?

Tags: java, file

I download a Java project from network, you see bellow:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But I do not understand the `*.inx`, `*.properties` file, and the `fodict.bin`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How can I get the data from the `fodict.bin`?  I want to convert the dictionary data from the `fodict.bin` to a `.sql` file, so I can put to the database.

Comment: You can't unless you know the format the `.bin` file was written in.

Comment: @Sedrick Why would you assume a .bin file is text-based?

Comment: I guess I am wrong.